# correct way of deleting parent object based on child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to delete a parent based on a nested object.
For more information, I'm trying to make a bug-tracker, something much simpler to jira.
I have a projects collection, when a user creates a project he ends up in the database as a user with admin = true.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "642beae28c88778b7ec345c3",
            "name": "test three",
            "priority": 0,
            "users": [
                {
                    "admin": true,
                    "role": 3,
                    "_id": "642aa3df4add92f56fe8caab"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2023-04-04T09:16:18.875Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-04T09:16:18.875Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "642bec891443d0d5528e4469",
            "name": "test one",
            "priority": 0,
            "users": [
                {
                    "admin": true,
                    "role": 3,
                    "_id": "642aa3df4add92f56fe8caab"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2023-04-04T09:23:21.480Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-04T09:23:21.480Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

I would like to check if the user is admin and if so delete the project by using req.params.id so far i have this much

```
export const deleteProject = async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  const { _id: userId } = req.user;
  const projectId = req.params.id;

  console.log(projectId);
  try {
    const checkIfAdmin = await Project.find({ "users._id": userId });
    console.log(checkIfAdmin[1], "type of this");

    // const projects = await Project.findByIdAndDelete({
    //   projectId,
    // });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "Success",
      message: "Project has been succesfuly deleted",
      params: projectId,
      data: checkIfAdmin,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "Failed to delete this projects",
      value: projectId,
    });
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

req.user comes from my auth middleware.

Also would love to get some pointers on how to correctly handle user roles in regard to projects and then in future tickets to each project and comments to each ticket.

I have tried all the above outlined

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to this problem,
If there is a cleaner/ better way, please add the answer

```
export const deleteProject = async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  const { _id: userId } = req.user;
  const projectId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const projects = await Project.find({ "users._id": userId });
    if (projects.length !== 0) {
      projects.map((el) => {
        el.users.map(async (user) => {
          //check if user is admin
          if (user.admin == true) {
            await Project.findByIdAndDelete(projectId);
            res.status(200).json({
              status: "Success",
              message: "Project has been succesfuly deleted",
              params: projectId,
              data: projects,
            });
          } else
            res.status(400).json({
              status: "Failed",
              message: "You are not the admin",
            });
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ status: "Failed", message: "No projects found" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "Failed to delete this projects",
      value: projectId,
    });
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```